# Is props still good for function component accessing params in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am converting class component to function component. `Event` component used to be like this:

```
class Event extends React.Component {
    //do something
  }
```

Now `Event` is a function component:

```
function Event() {
  // do something
}
```

Some params are passed to the `Event` as below :

```
const EventScreen = (props) => (<Event {...props} name={name} address={address})
```

In class `Event`, the `name` and `address` can be accessed via `this.props.name` and `this.props.address`.

After converting `Event` into function component, how to access the `name` and `address`? Can it be `props.name` and `props.address`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you access it this way:

```
function Event(props) {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about using a [Function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components); `props` is passed as the first argument to the function:

```
function Event(props) {
  // props.name etc exist
}
```

You can also do deconstruction for easier use:

```
function Event({name, address}) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the [`function component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) there is no need to use `this`, you can directly access to the props like below:

```js
function Event(props) {
  console.log(props);
}
```

But I offer you to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for a function component like below:

```js
const Event = ({ name, address }) => {
  console.log(name, address);
}
```

Comment: `this` is for class component